# Lower the resolution of an image to a specific number of pixels in Python

Tags: python, image

I'm trying to lower the resolution of images to 250.000 pixels using Python but I don't want them to have a specific height or width so that it depends on the image in question. I've been looking at options like `resize_thumbnail` or use Pillow but in both I have to set the maximum width or height.

Comment: Please read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]. Your question is currently very broad and unclear. It would be better if you post your actual attempt and show how your output differs from the one you're expecting

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are trying to achieve? Can't you use some basic arithmetic to derive the maximum width or height from the number of pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must know the resolution of the image you begin with, therefore scaling it to 250k pixels is just a matter of proportions.

```
# With Pillow you can read the size property of the image
width, height = image.size
res_0 = width * height
res_1 = 250000

# You need a scale factor to resize the image to res_1
scale_factor = (res_1/res_0)**0.5
resized = image.resize(width * scale_factor, height * scale_factor)
```

---

Out of curiosity I digged a little deeper to resize to the highest resolution that keeps the aspect ratio of the original image, if it exists.
An image with an aspect ratio of W:H can be divided in W×H squares whose side is the GCD of the width and height of the resolution.
After finding W and H, what's left to do is to calculate the highest multiples of W and H that fit the given resolution, in our case 250k pixels.

```
import math

# With Pillow you can read the size property of the image  
width, height = 2538, 1080
res_0 = width * height
res_1 = 1920*1080 # 518400

# You need a scale factor to resize the image to Res1
scale_factor = (res_1/res_0)**0.5
ratio = width/height

# The 
max_width = width * scale_factor
max_height = height * scale_factor

# Greates Common Divider and W:H
GCD = math.gcd(width, height)
W = width / GCD
H = height / GCD

ratio_width = math.floor(max_resized[0] / W) * W
ratio_height = math.floor(max_resized[1] / H) * H

scaled_size = (max_width, max_height)
# If GCD > 1 the image can be scaled keeping the original aspect ratio
# otherwise it'll approximated
if (GCD > 1):
    scaled_size = (ratio_width, ratio_height)
    
resized = image.resize(scaled_size)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am working with a data set so every image has a different ratio but your aswer is really helpful. The problem I can encounter is that the is to get decimals when finding the proportions but I will round them.

Comment: @marcb you can try the updated code, but you must check if the resolution that keeps the aspect ratio is large enough

Comment: Wow thank you so much!! It has been a great help to me, I am super grateful. This contribution will improve my code a lot, it had not occurred to me to use the greates common divider, great idea.